# Cannot scroll down to the end inside a tab panel in center layout

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-layout

I am struggling with the following problem, any hint would be appreciated.

In my jQuery UI layout in the center panel I put a jQuery UI tab, within
this tab I put some contents. Contents is taking more space than available,
I would like to have a scroll bar only on the containing `div`, not on the
whole tab nor on the center panel. Indeed I would like to have tab headers always visible.

What I did:

- setting `center__contentSelector` for the jQuery UI layout centre panel
  to the tab widget (so I have my header and footer displayed ok)
- setting `overflow: hidden` both on the layout centre panel and the tab
  widget
- setting `overflow: auto` on the `div` of the contents
- giving heights to both the tab widget and the contents' `div`

The final result looks fine, however **the scroll bar can't display
the last items**, whatever I tried. It's impossible to scroll to the limit.

Here is a fiddle that shows what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/mguijarr/288yaz15/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

your div's height seems to have extra 80 pixels each time, because of the tab title part. simply subtract those 80 pixels from 100%:

```
#tab_1 {
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    background: #00ffff;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

<kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/288yaz15/3/)**</kbd>